# Private function including variables

Tags: php, function, private

I'm trying to include [Crop-avatar](https://github.com/fengyuanchen/cropper) to a small project I'm fixing.

I have included the files and it uploads and looks good, but I don't get the possibility to include a `$_GET` variable inside the include script. I'm guessing it have something to do with the "Private functions" that the codes uses.

URL like: `index.php?id=12345`

```
<?php
include("Crop.php");

class CropAvatar
{
    private $src;
    private $data;
    private $dst;
    private $type;
    private $extension;
    private $msg;

    private function setDst()
    {
        $this->dst = 'images/' . date('YmdHis') . '.png';
    }
}
```

https://github.com/fengyuanchen/cropper/blob/master/examples/crop-avatar/crop.php

I would like to change this:

```
$this->dst = './images/' . date('YmdHis') . '.png';
```

to something like this:

```
$this->dst = './images/' . $trimmeduserid . '.png';
```

Any tips or point of direction on how I could fix this?

Regards,
Jan

Comment: Too much code. Please provide the minimal code needed to reproduce your problem. Remove anything that has nothing to do with the problem.

Comment: Thanx, updated now.

Comment: Can't you use `post` ?

Answer (score 0):

It should be really simple:

```
// Change
$this->dst = 'images/' . date('YmdHis') . '.png';

// to
$this->dst = 'images/' . trim($_GET['id']) . '.png';
```

Comment: I thought so to, but then it only rename the file to .png

Comment: If you don't have ID in $_GET array, then you don't have URL as described in question